# RStudio after reboot

Tags: r, rstudio

Yesterday I left my Mac with running `xgboost` in RStudio and the battery died.

after I charged and launched my laptop I found RStudio in the same state as before: It looks like it's still running `xgboost`

I also checked it with `ps` command and I can see this:

```
 %CPU  %MEM  TT  STAT STARTED         TIME    COMMAND
100.0  14.2  ??  R    Tue09PM   3791:27.47   rsession
```

Does RStudio save its state and can recover after power outage?
How can I check that it's actually doing any job?

Comment: meanwhile, calculations were finished, so, yes, RStudio can outlive a reboot